# How to select choices in groups using Django

Tags: python, django, widget, forms

I am using Django MultiSelect forms and I am trying to group my selections. Is it possible if I choose the group name "St", and all selections in this group will be selected?
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmcLf.png)

I have tried to pass in a list of strings with the name of each sub-selection, but Django renders unicode thus my attempt failed.

```
class DeFactorForm1(forms.Form):
FACTOR_CHOICES = (
 ('"a", "b", "c"', 'St'),
 ('St',(('a', 'a'),
 ('b', 'b'),
 ('c', 'c'))),
 ...
```

Any idea is appreciated!